# Jump to ID or Class Selector in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sublimetext3, atom-editor

In both Atom and Sublime text, I was able to jump to a particular selector in a CSS file by pressing Cntrl-R and typing the name of the selector.

Is there an extension that can replicate this feature for Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1):

You maybe looking for this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek

Press Ctrl+P then type your selector.

Comment: Sorry that extension is not working. I am running ubuntu. Ctrl+P is used to open files.

Comment: +Anwar Hossain Got it. Its Ctrl+Shift+O.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [CSS Navigation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pucelle.vscode-css-navigation) which *(as the documentation says)*:

> At beginning, this project is a fork from vscode-css-peek, which uses
> vscode-css-languageservice as CSS parser, I just fixed some Scss
> nesting reference issues.
>
> Then I found it eats so much CPU & memory.
> E.g., one of my project has 280 CSS files out of 5500 files, includes
> 6 MB codes. On my MacBook Pro, it needs 7s to load (1.3s to search
> files and 6s to parse), and uses 700 MB memory.
>
> Otherwise it keeps
> parsing files every time you input a character, if CSS document is
> more than 100 KB, CPU usage will keep high when inputing. Finally I
> decided to implement a new css parser, which also supports Scss & Less
> naturally, as a result I created a new extension. The CSS parser is
> very simple and not 100% strict, but it's fast and very easy to
> extand.
>
> Now it costs about 0.8s to search files, and 0.5s to parse
> them. Memory usage in caching parsed results is only about 40 MB.
> Otherwise, all the functionality will be started only when required by
> default, so CSS files are loaded only when you begin to search
> definitions or others. You may change this behavior by specify
> preloadCSSFiles option.
>
> After files loaded, the extension will track
> file and directory changes, creations, removals automatically, and
> reload them if needed. Further more, I found the extension can support
> class name and id completion by the same core, so I do it with very
> few codes. Finding references uses another core, I implement it
> because my work have a heavy CSS part, and I love refactoring CSS
> codes. I believe few people would need it.

Comment: The latest version of [CSS Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) (which is the extension CSS Navigation is forked from) has made a lot of optimizations since then. That's the recommended extension once again :)

Answer (score 0):

As @anwar-hossain said, check out [CSS Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek). It does this nicely. Just use `Cmd+Shift+O` (to search in the opened file) - or `Cmd+T` (to search across your codebase)